# Warning C4503 when using "#pragma warning" around Boost includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I get a C4503 warning message ("decorated name length exceeded, name was truncated", 3 times) when compiling the following C++ code in VS 2010, with Boost 1.4.9:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

#pragma warning (push, 1)
#include <boost/units/quantity.hpp>
#include <boost/units/si/plane_angle.hpp>
#pragma warning (pop)

using namespace boost::units;

typedef std::pair<quantity<si::plane_angle>, quantity<si::plane_angle> > Section;

std::vector<Section> getEmptyVector()
{
    std::vector<Section> sections;
    return sections;
}
```

The thing that puzzles me is that the warning goes away only when I **remove** the `#pragma` directives. Is there an explanation for this, or does the compiler have a bug?

Comment: Boost tries to suppress unnecessary warnings for different compilers. If you see a lot of those, file a bug report with the specific compiler, warning level and header that triggers the warning.

Comment: I had to read that question three times before I realized it had nothing to do with global warming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if it's a warning the boost guys have decided to suppress for the Visual C++ compiler.

From [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/Guidelines/WarningsGuidelines#SpecificWarningsandSuggestedActions.):

> Warning:  C4503   decorated name length exceeded
>   Suggestions: Suppress. (Note that \boost\config\compiler\visualc.hpp includes this global > suppression...)! Suppression: #pragma warning(disable:4503)

Now for the complier. Note the following code:

```
#pragma warning (push, 1)
#pragma warning (disable:4503)

// C4503.cpp
// compile with: /W1 /EHsc /c
// C4503 expected
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Field{};

typedef std::map<std::string, Field> Screen;
typedef std::map<std::string, Screen> WebApp;
typedef std::map<std::string, WebApp> WebAppTest;
typedef std::map<std::string, WebAppTest> Hello;
Hello MyWAT;

#pragma warning (pop)
```

I just tweaked the Microsoft help example for this [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/074af4b6.aspx)

if you put the `#pragma warning (disable:4503)` **after** the push, you **get** the warning. If you put it **before**, there are **no** warnings. That means the code above generates C4503 warnings, even though it was disabled.

Comment: So would it be reasonably safe to just ignore this warning?

Comment: Soo... why does DISabling the warning after the push, effectively, ENable the warning?

Answer (score 1):

Boost causes that error a lot and IIRC (from v 1.2ish) it manages warnings in the boost libraries that are considered harmless.
You are seeing that warning because you're doing something they don't expect and fouling up their warning management.

Comment: I'm compiling my project with warning level 4, and if I don't selectively change it with `#pragma` directives when including Boost header files, I get a lot of warnings. Is there a more 'Boost-friendly' way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to this question can be found in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The pragma warning( pop ) pops the last warning state pushed onto the stack. Any changes that you made to the warning state between push and pop are undone.

Any changes to the warning state between push and pop are undone. Which means, whatever changes the boost-headers themselves make (and they disable 4503 apparently) is undone.
You could reinstate the disabling of 4503 after your pop.